# How can I safely defeat scythes and centipedes from crashed spaceships?

Tags: rimworld

Typically my strategy for defeating enemies involves base defense - they walk through my turret kill room and I have a distinct advantage. This works very well for invading groups of humanoid enemies.

However, when an ancient alien ship crashes, I have to go to them to destroy the object, or face various negative effects. Once aggroing the enemies inside, they don't seem to follow me back and attack my base. If I stay and fight, my troops get slaughtered by miniguns and railguns, losing many colonists (and limbs).

How can I fight these aliens most effectively without losing half my colonists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use M24s at max range. The Centipedes will NOT follow you IF you manage to stay out of their range. Focus the scythes first. They have the range of the bolt action rifle, but you can kill them easy with the 3 tiles more range of your M24s. Later focus on the Centipedes. They are very much no problem but start with Inferno > Mini > Blaster.
Against 20-30 Centis and same amount of Scythes you can manage to win without receiving any hit at all. But you need half a dozen of snipers and a few in-game days to clear them.

The tactic does not work with attacking Mechanoids. I have 40 Centis attacking my base and no idea how to fight them down. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the late response; this definitely works (sniping from long distance) as long as you micro it correctly and avoid any scyther snipers in return. A little cheesy, and I suspect it will get fixed shortly. As for attacking Mechs, I don't have much trouble with them. They all die easily in my killbox. I supplement the killbox with charge rifle colonists behind a sandbag; the charge rifle does good damage against the centipedes.

Answer (score 1):

Build power lines out around the ship and set up a number of turrets.  Once everything is in place (and your colonists are far away) set a turret to manually attack the ship to spawn the enemies.  If you have enough turrets and prioritize the small guys, you should be in good shape.

Comment: Note though that simply building around a ship can cause them to emerge.